# Azure AD Graph API - Constantly returning 403 for getMemberGroups method

Tags: java, azure, spring-security, azure-ad-graph-api

I have Java Spring MVC application that is successfully integrated with Azure AD for signing on.

However, when I want to list users group membership, I am getting Error code 403. When I am testing manually from the Azure AD Graph Explorer its working fine.

### This is the code I am working on:

```
    URL url = new URL(String.format("https://graph.windows.net/%s/users/%s/getMemberGroups?api-version=%s", tenant, userId, apiVersion, accessToken));

    String json = "{\n" +
            "    \"securityEnabledOnly\" : true\n" +
            "}";

    byte[] postDataBytes = json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "36");
    conn.setRequestProperty("api-version", apiVersion);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", accessToken);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
```

### Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

The access token I am getting like in the Microsoft example from Refresh Token. The same function is working fine for other API methods such as /users/. I guess there are some parameters that need to be configured in the Azure for group membership access. However, it is working fine from the Graph explorer when I sign in with same user.(https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/).

Do someone has complete working example with all steps that need to be configured in order to read users group membership.

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: Which permissions does the app have? The effective permissions are always the least privileges from the app and the user, so even if the user can do it, it can't be done if the app can't do it.

Comment: Hi, I tried with almost all combinations of the delegated permissions. Even if I add all of them, I am still getting 403. But if it works in the Graph explorer, why it should not work from my web application with same user ? Is there something else that need to be configured ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this document :[Permission scopes | Graph API concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes) .

You could find how to choose permission scopes that provide the least level of privilege needed by your app. As @juunas said,for delegated scopes, the actual access granted to the app will be the least privileged combination (intersection) of the access granted by the scope and the privileges of the signed-in user.Please try to grant User.Read.All and Group.Read.All permissions to app .